# What are the recommended configuration for improving After Effects CS6 perfomance?

Tags: performance, adobe-after-effects

Everything was fine regarding my performance while using After Effects CS6. Suddenly it became really slow to pre-render the frames of my text animation (and started hanging a lot). It is interesting because I did not do any big changes to this video, which is pretty simple.

If anyone has nice advices on how could I improve my After Effects configuration in order to run it smoother, please share it here your suggestions (change AE settings, add external HD, etc).

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-3632QM] @ 2.20 GHz (4 cores)
RAM: 8GB
OS: Windows 8 Pro 64-bit
C Drive: SATA: 913 GB free - Write speed 107 MB/s
D Drive: Samsung SSD MZMPC032HBCD 8 GB free- Write speed 85 MB/s
```

Comment: It may seem trivial, but is there anything else running that is hogging resources? A recently installed program or perhaps a hanging process?

Comment: 1) As Moses already asked. Is the computer slower, not just After Effects? 2) Please run resmon or taskmanager and see if anything is consuming any resource. 3) Did you update windows recently. Partially to make sure no virus in taking resources. Partially because a .net update can take a long time and make your computer slow for hours.

Answer (score 0):

See this page for resources about making After Effects work faster: http://adobe.ly/eV2zE7

See this page for information about hardware for After Effects: http://adobe.ly/pRYOuk